# Update JSONB in Postgres using R

Tags: r, postgresql, r-glue

as the title states I am trying to update a jsonb field from inside R. I have several changes to apply. The original dataset is created by a third party application but needs to be corrected for several rows.

The following statement is working fine as a database statement:

```
UPDATE histories set meta=jsonb_set(meta,'{product}','"55-AB"') WHERE id = 17983;
```

Now, I need to update the "product" field for several different ids.
Assume the following dataframe as an example:

```
df<-data.frame(product=c("55-AB","567-C","UTG-98"),
               id=c(17983,54388,20000))
```

Usually I would use `sql_glue` from the `glue` package but I run out of quotes generating the above queries dynamically.

```
sql_glue("UPDATE histories set meta=jsonb_set(meta,'{product}','"{`df$product`}"') WHERE id = {`df$id`};")

Error: unexpected '{' in "sql_glue("UPDATE histories set meta=jsonb_set(meta,'{pesticide}','"{"
```

I am running into problems with the quotation. Any idea how to get around this?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with R, but postgres supports using double-dollars as string delimiters. See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING

Comment: Thanks, that was a perfect hint. I had to do some adaptations to create dynamic SQL-Statements but the double-dollars where the solution.